# How to move uiview from one point to another using Core Motion

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion, devicemotion

I am creating a app where i need to move uiview according to device movement. As i researched this can be done by using core motion kit. When i used accelerometerData, gyroData, deviceMotion to get motion values but i am unable to calculate how to use these values to move uiview.

```
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {

    xAcc = round(accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 100)/100
    yAcc = round(accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 100)/100
    zAcc = round(accelerometerData.acceleration.z * 100)/100

}

if let gyroData = motionManager.gyroData {

    xGyro = round(gyroData.rotationRate.x * 100)/100
    yGyro = round(gyroData.rotationRate.y * 100)/100
    zGyro = round(gyroData.rotationRate.z * 100)/100

}

self.movement_view.frame.origin.x += xGyro
self.movement_view.frame.origin.y += yGyro
```

In short how much a view should move in x or y direction according to these values.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Do you want it to move as though it's a marble on your screen? Do you want it to move like the subtle parallax shift on iOS home screen backgrounds? Do you want it to move opposite to device movement? Your question is too broad and you are likely going to have to simply solve this by trying things and seeing which one feels right for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @IanMacDonald for comment. Actually that dot will be used to navigate user / user can select an item on screen without touch. He will just move device and bring the dot to the required position to navigate to another page.

Comment: You have provided motivation for it to move, but you have not described _how_ you want it to move. What you have done _will_ move the dot. It is up to you now to define the algorithm that shapes its motion curve to your design.